Determining if two functions appear in the same place in source code
Say I have the following JS:
function counter() {
  var i = 0;
  return function() {
    return i++;
  }
}

var counter1 = counter();
var counter2 = counter();

Here, counter1 !== counter2 because they both come from different calls of the counter() closure.
Even still, both counter1 and counter2 refer to functions with declarations that share the same position in the source code.
Without doing anything special to the function declarations directly (but maybe with prototype manipulation), is there any way to determine if both variables point to functions sharing the same function declaration? Or is this truly not possible?
Now, one could do counter1.toString() === counter2.toString(), but this of course fails in some cases, e.g.:
function counterA() {
  var i = 0;
  return function() {
    return i++;
  }
}
function counterB() {
  var i = 5;
  return function() {
    return i++;
  }
}

var counter1 = counterA();
var counter2 = counterB();

counter1.toString() === counter2.toString(); // but they're not in the same place

(Chrome's inspector, for instance, is aware of a function's declaration location. After running the second script above in Chrome's console, and then inspecting counter1 or counter2, one can click on the printed function and it jumps to the actual declaration's source.)

What exactly are you trying to find out that relates to the position in the source code? Because it sounds a bit like an XY problem and the Y of "find the source code position" might not be the best solution to whatever the X is.

The issue more specifically is that the two returned functions are the results of two separate function instantiations (by the function expression in the return statement). They are distinct objects.

There's no standard method to get the function object out of a closure. If there were a property like code, you could use counter1.code == counter2.code.
